# Getting top-level window by widget

Tags: c++, qt, hook

I'm hooking the `QPainter::drawText()` function of a Qt5 application on Windows.
My goal is to identify the native handle of the top-level-window to which the text is painted. First, I'm getting the associated widget.

```
QWidget *widget = static_cast<QWidget *>(painter->device());
```

So it should be possible to find the corresponding top-level window/widget.
But it's harder than I thought. This is what I tried so far:

```
while (widget->parentWidget())
    widget = widget->parentWidget();

HWND hwnd = (HWND) widget->winId();
```

No success. The top-parent is never the desired window.

```
QApplication::topLevelWidgets()
```

Showed me that one single window contains several top-level-widgets (including the one I'm looking for).

I also tried `QApplication::topLevelAt(widget->mapToGlobal(QPoint()))`

In some cases this actually works, but not reliably.
Depending on text and window position I'm getting a `AccessViolationException`,
so this is not an option.

By testing `widget->testAttribute(Qt::WA_NativeWindow)`
I found out that most of the widgets are non-native [Alien Widgets](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#native-widgets-vs-alien-widgets).

This is how I get the (what I call) top-level window.

```
WinAPI.EnumChildWindows(
    WinAPI.GetDesktopWindow(),
    new EnumWindowsProc(this.EnumWindowsCallback), 0);
```

Then I check the window titles to find the handles I'm interested in.

I'm not able to find a relation from any (low-level) widget to the (top-level) widget that holds the window title.

Comment: To clarify: Are you looking for the handle of the first "Container 'Client'", or your "Top-Level-Window"? Can you show some code or describe how your "top-level widgets" relate to that single window?

Comment: Please note that using the Windows API or a third-party utility to paint in Qt is highly unlikely to work reliably unless you embed a native widget and paint on that.

Comment: I don't want to draw anything. I'm intercepting the whole text output of the application and compare each string to some keywords.
If I find a match, I want to map it to one of the application's open windows.

Comment: I don't have any souce code of the application I'm intercepting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's done! I found a solution for my problem.

Each windows has it's own thread.

```
int threadId = WinApi.GetWindowThreadProcessId(wndHandle, IntPtr.Zero)
```

With it I use [EnumThreadWindows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633495(VS.85).aspx)
to get a list of all window-handles created by this thread.

Finally I check wheather `widget->effectiveWinId()` is in the list.

So I can map each widget to its corresponding window!

Answer (score 4):

For the `QWidget` that acts as a top level window, [call `QWidget::window()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#window).

For the nearest parent with a native handle, [call `QWidget::nativeParentWidget()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#nativeParentWidget).

Calling `winId()` *forces the widget to acquire a native window handle if it does not have one*, which isn't your goal. A top level window will always have a native id, so `(HWND)window()->winId()` is fine. Note that this is *usually* the same as [calling `QWidget::effectiveWinId()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#effectiveWinId).

Comment: Very good hint! So if you deal with non-native (alien) widgets, avoid using QWidget::winId() for debugging purposes, like I did :P

Comment: Yes. `widget->nativeParentWidget()->effectiveWinId()`
gives me the nearest native parent handle. But unfortunately it's never the wanted :(

Answer (score 0):

My 5 cents:

```
widget->backingStore()->window()->winId()
```